# How to exclude a @Configuration class when using @WebMvcTest with spring-boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit4

I am writing junits for a rest controller. I want only minimal context to be loaded which is related to the controller and I think that is how `@WebMvcTest` loads the context. But the junit is loading complete Spring context and it is failing as some of the beans can not be created.

I have searched and read through many questions on stackoverflow and none of the solutions worked to exclude specific configuration. How can I load a minimal context when writing junits for controllers? Or is there any way to exclude some configuration classes? I am using Spring-boot 2.2.2.RELEASE, Java 8 and Junit 4.

Junit (where I have tried to exclude loading of some beans and configurations but it doesn't work):

```java
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(controllers = OrderController.class, excludeFilters = {@Filter(classes = Configuration.class), @Filter(type = FilterType.REGEX, pattern = "com\\.foo\\..*")})
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap:false" })
public class OrderControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    private OrderService orderService;


    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        mockMvc.perform(get("/internal/order/123"));
        // Further code to verify the response
    }

}
```

Controller

```java
@Slf4j
@Validated
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/internal")
public class OrderController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;

    @GetMapping(value = "/order/{orderId}", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<RegularContributionOrder> retrieveRegularContributionOrder(@NotNull @PathVariable("orderId") String orderId)
            throws OrderNotFoundException {

        RegularContributionOrder order = orderService.retrieve(orderId);

        return new ResponseEntity<RegularContributionOrder>(order, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Configuration class which I want to exclude from context loading

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ImportResource({ "classpath:spring/service-config-one.xml", "classpath:spring/service-config-two.xml" })
public class OrderServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("classpath:resourcebundles/error-messages.properties");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Spring boot main class:

```java
@EnableJms
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.foo.services", "com.bar" })
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { SomeConfiguration.class})
public class BootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected final SpringApplicationBuilder configure(final SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(BootApplication .class);
    }

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        SpringApplication.run(BootApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share your main class that is annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` as well please?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Thanks for the comment. Question updated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your use of `@ComponentScan` has disabled the filters that are used by `@WebMvcTest` to limit the types of components that are found by scanning.

You should remove `@ComponentScan` from your main application class and use the `basePackages` attribute on `@SpringBootApplication` instead.

You should also move `@EnableJms` and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to a separate `@Configuration` class so that they are not enabled when using `@WebMvcTest`. Alternatively, you may be able to remove them entirely as they are covered by Spring Boot’s auto-configuration.

Comment: works amazing. It should be the parameter "basePackages" in @SpringBootApplication instead of "backPackages". Probably a small typo

Comment: Thanks, @Prometheus. I've fixed the typo.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson how could we use "@SpringBootApplication" "basePackages" and exclude some class without using "@ComponentScan" excludeFilter since the exclude attribute in SpringBootApplication annotation is for exclude auto configuration class only.

Comment: @ChiDov You'd have to copy the `@ComponentScan` from `@SpringBootApplication` and configure additional exclude filters.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson if I am using `@ComponentScan` in Spring context configuration file, it will disabled the filters that are used by @WebMvcTest to limit the types of components that are found by scanning like you mention above.

Comment: @ChiDov That's what I said to copy the declaration from `@SpringBootApplication` including the exclude filters that it declares. You can then add additional filters of your own. Please ask a separate question if you need further guidance. Comments aren't really the right place for this.

Answer (score 2):

When your test classes located in test folder and run with "test" profile then your real configuration class will be excluded. Here is an example of how I configure spring boot test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = IntegrationApplication.class,
    webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class MyControllerTest {
```

=================================

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class IntegrationApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(IntegrationApplication.class, args);
}
```

Comment: What is `IntegrationApplication`? Spring boot main class?

Comment: Yes. This class for tests only. There is another spring boot main which is "real". Also you can profile your configuration class, like "@Profile("!test")" to exclude it from test context.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. @Andy Wilkinson 's answer worked for me.